# Raspberry PI Zero rebooting every day or two

Tags: pi-zero

I am not sure if I have a bad board.
I have a raspberry PI Zero with a camera attached.  It cannot reliably run more than 24 hours and I have never see it do 72 hours.
I have a heat sink on it, I have taken the lid off so it gets a lot of air, and I am using a robust 2amp power supply.
Am I using the wrong product to expect it to run continuously?
Is it worth buying another PI Zero board?

Comment: OK. So the longest times is 3 days.  But can I have more statistics : (1) What is the shortest time, say 5 minutes? (2) What is the frequency, say, at least once a day, at most 3 times a day, average 1.5 times a day? (3)  What is the most probable auto shut down time, say 8am to 9am when everybody is switching on air con etc, (4) what is the lease probably time, say 11pm to 7 am when almost everybody goes to bed? And some more non statistical questions:  (4) Do you store camera images that might cause the  ”stack“ overflow, and that you empty stack after each reboot?

Comment: What make and model of power supply? What are you doing with the camera? What OS? What software? I run my Pi Zero W 24/7 monitoring water supply without any problems.

Comment: I am driving the board hard.  It is running `motion`, making thumbnails (using image magic) of some of the saved images, using WiFi.  I have a heat sink but no fan.  It does get hot.  The power supply is from 'TT Electronics', 5.1V and 2.5 amps